# How to call method on every request on service with { scope: Scope.REQUEST }?

Tags: nestjs

How to call method on every request on service with { scope: Scope.REQUEST } ?

It doesn't work:

```
export class UsersService implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log(`The module has been initialized.`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate a little bit more about what you're trying to do and what challenges you are facing. Are you trying to say that you want to re-initialize an entire NestJS module on every request?

Comment: @JesseCarter Yes, I want to get geoip info on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Its cleary mentioned in nest document that lifecycle events will not be triggered for request scoped classes.

> The lifecycle hooks listed above are not triggered for request-scoped
> classes. Request-scoped classes are not tied to the application
> lifecycle and their lifespan is unpredictable. They are exclusively
> created for each request and automatically garbage-collected after the
> response is sent.

what you can do is, call or implement your function inside constructor.

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

    @Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
    export class UsersService {
      constructor() {
        console.log(`The module has been initialized.`);
      }
    }
```

Or implement a middleware, that seems to be an exact fit to your requirement.

[Nest Middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware)

Comment: could you expand on the idea of adding a middleware to do this?

Comment: @Zephyr  `How to call method on every request` : **That's a middleware is for**.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle hooks are not triggered for request-scoped classes.

[image]

As a workaround compose a middleware and administer it to the module where you utilize the request-scoped service. Inside the middleware, perform the initialization of the service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class InitReqScopedSvcMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(public readonly reqScopedService: ReqScopedService) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await this.reqScopedService.initialize();

    next();
  }
}

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ReqScopedService {
  public async initialize() {
    // initialization logic goes here
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [ReqScoppedService],
  exports: [ReqScoppedService],
})
export class MyModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(InitReqScopedSvcMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems that you forgot apply `Injectable` decorator to your service. According [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes), it should looks like:

```js
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log(`The module has been initialized.`);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set this class as a provider of your module. Please, [find documentation about it here](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers)